# How to drag and drop item from list to another item in list and interchange their positions

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I have a list field with multiple items. I want to select one item from list and drag and drop to another item in the list. After dropping the item on another item the position of items should be interchanged.
(Example:- if i select 1st item from list and drag and drop this item to 4th item in list
 after drop that item position of both item should be changed 1st item on 4th position and 4th item on 1st position)

i don't know how to do this.Please help me to complete this task.

```java
    public class ListScreen extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback {
    // private ObjectChoiceField choices;
    private int x, y;
    int start = 0 , end=0;
    private int startPos;
//  private int pos;
    private ObjectListField list;
    private Object[] listData = new Object[] { "Ram", "Sunny", "Ramit",
            "Vishal","Ravinder","Manoj","Ravi","Vikas","Santosh","Ravi","Deepak","Sharma","Nvn" };

    public ListScreen() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        list = new ObjectListField(FOCUSABLE);
        list.setRowHeight(45);
        list.setCallback(this);
        list.set(listData);
        add(list);
    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
            int y, int width) {
        graphics.drawText(listData[index].toString(), 25, y + 10);

    }

    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
        return listData[index];
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
        return getPreferredWidth();
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    // protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int
    // time) {
    //
    // return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
    // }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        int eventCode = message.getEvent();

        // Get the screen coordinates of the touch event
        int touchX = message.getX(1);
        int touchY = message.getY(1);
        if (eventCode == TouchEvent.CLICK) {


            calculateStart(touchY);
            // Dialog.alert("You clicked at (" + touchX + "," + touchY + ")");
        }

        if (eventCode == TouchEvent.MOVE) {

            x = touchX;
            y = touchY;

            invalidate();
        }
        if (eventCode == TouchEvent.UNCLICK) {
            int unClickx = message.getX(1);
            int unClicky = message.getY(1);
            System.out.println("unclick at:" + unClickx + "::::" + unClicky);
            calculatePosition(unClicky);
        }



        return true;
    }


    private void calculatePosition(int dy) {
        if (dy != 0) {

                end = dy / 45;
                System.out.println(start + ":::" + end);
                Object temp = listData[start];
                listData[start] = listData[end];
                listData[end] = temp;
                invalidate();

        }

    }
    private void calculateStart(int dy){
        if(dy!=0)
        start = dy/45;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your question. And the title doesn't have any relation to the question (hard to figure out the relation if exists).

Comment: I think it's tough task to do in BlackBerry. For this we may need to use some `VerticalFieldManager` manager instead of customized `ListField`. And After identifying a drag action, we need to enter in animation mode, and regarding the touch movement (mouse movement) we need to draw selected item from `VerticalFieldManager` in new position.

Comment: Rupak i agree. But i have to take ListField or ObjectChoiceField for add items because i have multiple items. i will take one VerticalFieldManager and add that ObjectListField to that VerticalFieldManager. Can u add code for that.

Comment: I didn't implement that kind of UI Field earlier.

Comment: I have a code for that.but its working only on single screen when items are more than screen and i scroll that field after that its not working fine.checkout this code.

Comment: Rupak Please see my code and help me. i edit my Q.

Comment: I saw your code, and I will let you know if I can help you (need more time :().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***UPDATED FOR BOTH TOUCH AND NON-TOUCH DEVICES***]: Try the the following code; I've tested on Torch (9800), Storm (9550), Bold (9700):

```java
import net.rim.device.api.system.Characters;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory;

public class ListTestScreen extends MainScreen {
    private VerticalFieldManager mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager();
    public ListTestScreen() {
        mainManager.add(new LabelField("My Title"));
        mainManager.add(new LabelField("My List:"));
        mainManager.add(new MyList());
        mainManager.add(new LabelField("Something else"));
        add(mainManager);
    }
}

class MyList extends VerticalFieldManager implements ListFieldCallback {
    private int  mouseDownY, mouseUpY;
    private static int rowHeight = 45;
    private int mouseDownRowIndex, mouseUpRowIndex;
    int firstSelectedRow=-1, secondSelectedRow=-1;
    private int touchX;
    private int touchY;
    private boolean showShadow = false;

    private ObjectListField list;
    private Object[] listData = new Object[] { "Ram", "Sunny", "Ramit",
            "Vishal","Ravinder","Manoj","Ravi","Vikas","Santosh","Ravi","Deepak","Sharma","Nvn" };

    public MyList() {
        init();
        setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x0FCFC0, 0x0CCCC0, 0x09C9C0, 0x01C1C0));
    }

    private void init() {
        list = new ObjectListField(FOCUSABLE);
        list.setRowHeight(rowHeight);
        list.setCallback(this);
        list.set(listData);
        add(list);
    }

    private void interchangeRows(int r1, int r2) {
        Object temp = listData[r1];
        listData[r1] = listData[r2];
        listData[r2] = temp;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
            int y, int width) {
        graphics.drawText(listData[index].toString(), 25, y + 10);

    }

    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
        return listData[index];
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
        return getPreferredWidth();
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public int indexOfRowAt(int posY) {
        int index =(int) Math.floor(posY / rowHeight * 1.0); 
        return index;
    }


    protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time) {
        if(ch==Characters.SPACE) {
            if(firstSelectedRow ==-1) {
                firstSelectedRow = list.getSelectedIndex();
                return true;
            } else {
                secondSelectedRow = list.getSelectedIndex();
                if(firstSelectedRow == secondSelectedRow) {
                    firstSelectedRow = secondSelectedRow = -1;
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    interchangeRows(firstSelectedRow, secondSelectedRow);
                    firstSelectedRow = secondSelectedRow = -1;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        if(firstSelectedRow!=-1) {
            int x = 0, y = firstSelectedRow*rowHeight;
            int savedColor = graphics.getColor();
            int preAlpha = graphics.getGlobalAlpha();
            graphics.setGlobalAlpha(90) ;           
            graphics.setColor(0xFF22FF);

            graphics.fillRect(0, y, getWidth(), rowHeight);


            graphics.setColor(savedColor);
            graphics.setGlobalAlpha(preAlpha) ;
        }

        super.paint(graphics);

        if(showShadow && mouseDownRowIndex != -1) {
            int preAlpha = graphics.getGlobalAlpha();
            graphics.setGlobalAlpha(100) ;
            graphics.drawText(listData[mouseDownRowIndex].toString(), 25, touchY);
            graphics.setGlobalAlpha(preAlpha) ;
        }
    }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        int eventCode = message.getEvent();

        // Get the screen coordinates of the touch event
        touchX = message.getX(1);
        touchY = message.getY(1);       


        if(eventCode == TouchEvent.DOWN) {
            mouseDownY = touchY;
            mouseDownRowIndex = indexOfRowAt(mouseDownY);
            showShadow = true;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }        
        else if(eventCode == TouchEvent.UP) {
            showShadow = false;
            mouseUpY = touchY;
            mouseUpRowIndex = indexOfRowAt(mouseUpY);
            if(mouseDownRowIndex != mouseUpRowIndex) {
                interchangeRows(mouseDownRowIndex, mouseUpRowIndex);
                mouseDownRowIndex = mouseUpRowIndex = -1;
                return true;
            }
            mouseDownRowIndex = mouseUpRowIndex = -1;
            invalidate();
        } else if(eventCode == TouchEvent.MOVE) {
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }
}
```

[**EDITED:**]

**For touch-supported devices**: a shadow of text of the first selected item moves along with the cursor.

**For non-touch devices**: I've used **SPACEBAR** to select the items to interchange. Select an item, press SPACEBAR, select the second item, press **SPACEBAR** again, items interchanged !! Pressing **SPACEBAR** on an already selected item will deselect that item.

Let me know whether it worked or not.

> **Further enhancement of list field customization has been posted in**
>   this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292259/how-to-re-arrange-listfield-in-blackberry/10317642#10317642).

Comment: NO its not working fine.when i scroll the screen vertically after that its not working fine.

Comment: **Try now**, I've modified the code: now the `MyList` class extends  `VerticalFieldManager` rather than `MainScreen`. The problem on scrolling has been solved. Now you can use `MyList` class at any position you want.

Comment: My code is just to give you the idea how this can be done... you need to do the rest.

Comment: Hi its working fine on touch simulator. but how can i make code for non touch device or simulator.Do u have any idea. if u have than please help me or share code with me.

Comment: Try now, I've **updated** it for both **Touch** and **Non-Touch** devices.

Comment: HI HeartBeat its working fine on both Touch and Non-Touch.Thanks for the code.

Comment: HEY HeartBeat can we do one more thing in code.when i Press the SpaceBar on the item it show Selected item. After Select can we move (Drag) that item Vertically on the Screen.After Drag Drop the item on another item and changed their Position.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi HeartBeat Yesterday i had posted another Q With This name (How to Scroll Images Right and Left on FocusChanged in Blackberry) But no Body Solve my Problem.I know u can Solve my Problem. So please see That Q and Please Help me.