# Vertical Scroll TextField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, textfield, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new to Blackberry developement.I want do the custom textfield in my application.

I write a code for that But I want to scroll the text in that text field (if me text in textfield extends above 4 line.)

I use manager class to add vertical scroll but cant get it.

```
TextField textfield1=new TextField(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```

Anybody know how to give vertical scroll to the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```java
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

public class MyTextField extends VerticalFieldManager {

    private int fieldWidth;
    private int fieldHeight;
    private TextField textField;

    public MyTextField(int width, int height) {

        super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        fieldWidth = width;
        fieldHeight = height;

        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

        textField = new TextField() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                getManager().invalidate();
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };

        vfm.add(textField);
        add(vfm);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // draw the border of the text area;
        int color = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(0x00FFCC);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight);
        g.setColor(color);
        super.paint(g);
    }

    public void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        if (fieldWidth == 0) {
            fieldWidth = width;
        }
        if (fieldHeight == 0) {
            fieldHeight = height;
        }
        super.sublayout(fieldWidth, fieldHeight);
        setExtent(fieldWidth,fieldHeight);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textField.getText();
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        textField.setText(text);
    }
}
```

add it to your `Screen` or `Manager` by specifying the size like this:

```java
add(new MyTextField(200, 200));
```

Comment: Hi friend I appreciate your answer.It helps me a lot.Can I add my own scroll bar instead of default so that it looks nice.

Comment: @ani : In this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292259/how-to-re-arrange-listfield-in-blackberry/10317642#10317642)  I tried to give an idea how an `scroll-bar` can be drawn, though that is not about `TextArea`, but you can get an idea about implementing `scroll-bar`

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
HorizontalFieldManager HorizontalFieldManager=new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```

Then

```
TextField textfield1=new TextField();
HorizontalFieldManager.add(textfield1);
add(HorizontalFieldManager);
```

Comment: Sorry but I cant able to scroll in my textfield.I can see 3 line by but cant see remaining two.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom textbox as bellow.

```
    public class CustomTextBox extends Manager
{

/**
 * Default margins
 */
private final static int DEFAULT_LEFT_MARGIN = 10;
private final static int DEFAULT_RIGHT_MARGIN = 10;
private final static int DEFAULT_TOP_MARGIN = 5;
private final static int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_MARGIN = 5;

/**
 * Default paddings
 */
private final static int DEFAULT_LEFT_PADDING = 10;
private final static int DEFAULT_RIGHT_PADDING = 10;
private final static int DEFAULT_TOP_PADDING = 5;
private final static int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_PADDING = 5;

/**
 * Margins around the text box
 */
private int topMargin = DEFAULT_TOP_MARGIN;
private int bottomMargin = DEFAULT_BOTTOM_MARGIN;
private int leftMargin = DEFAULT_LEFT_MARGIN;
private int rightMargin = DEFAULT_RIGHT_MARGIN;

/**
 * Padding around the text box
 */
private int topPadding = DEFAULT_TOP_PADDING;
private int bottomPadding = DEFAULT_BOTTOM_PADDING;
private int leftPadding = DEFAULT_LEFT_PADDING;
private int rightPadding = DEFAULT_RIGHT_PADDING;

/**
 * Amount of empty space horizontally around the text box
 */
private int totalHorizontalEmptySpace = leftMargin + leftPadding 
                                 + rightPadding + rightMargin;

/**
 * Amount of empty space vertically around the text box
 */
private int totalVerticalEmptySpace = topMargin + topPadding 
                              + bottomPadding + bottomMargin;

/**
 * Minimum height of the text box required to display the text entered
 */
private int minHeight = getFont().getHeight() + totalVerticalEmptySpace;

/**
 * Width of the text box
 */
private int width = Display.getWidth();

/**
 * Height of the text box
 */
private int height = minHeight;

/**
 * Background image for the text box
 */
private EncodedImage backgroundImage;

/**
 * Bitmap version of the backgroundImage.
 * Needed to reduce the calculation overhead incurred by 
 * scaling of the given image
 * and derivation of Bitmap from the 
 * EncodedImage every time it is needed.
 */
private Bitmap bitmapBackgroundImage;

/**
 * The core element of this text box
 */
private EditField editField;
//private BasicEditField editField;

//private String entireText;

public CustomTextBox()
{
    // Let the super class initialize the core
    super(0);

    // An edit field is the sole field of this manager.
    editField = new EditField();
    //editField = new CustomEditField();
    add(editField);
}

public CustomTextBox(EncodedImage backgroundImage)
{
    this();        
    setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage);
}

public void setSize(int width, int height)
{
    boolean isChanged = false;

    if (width > 0 // Ignore invalid width
            && this.width != width)  
    {
        this.width = width;
        isChanged = true;
    }

    // Ignore the specified height if it is less 
    // than the minimum height required to display the text.
    if (height > minHeight && height != this.height)
    {
        this.height = height;
        isChanged = true;
    }

    // If width/height has been changed and background image 
    // is available, adapt it to the new dimension
    if (isChanged == true && backgroundImage != null)
    {
        bitmapBackgroundImage = getScaledBitmapImage(backgroundImage, 
                                this.width - (leftMargin+rightMargin),  
                                this.height - (topMargin+bottomMargin));
    }
}

public void setWidth(int width)
{

    if (width > 0 && width != this.width)
    {
        this.width = width;

        // If background image is available, adapt it to the new width
        if (backgroundImage != null)
        {
            bitmapBackgroundImage = getScaledBitmapImage(backgroundImage,
                                    this.width - (leftMargin+rightMargin),
                                    this.height - (topMargin+bottomMargin));
        }
    }
}

public void setHeight(int height)
{
    // Ignore the specified height if it is 
    // less than the minimum height required to display the text.
    if (height > minHeight)
    {
        this.height = height;

        // If background image is available, adapt it to the new width
        if (backgroundImage != null)
        {
            bitmapBackgroundImage = getScaledBitmapImage(backgroundImage,
                                    this.width - (leftMargin+rightMargin),  
                                    this.height - (topMargin+bottomMargin));
        }
    }
}

public void setBackgroundImage(EncodedImage backgroundImage)
{
    this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;

    // Consider the height of background image in 
    // calculating the height of the text box.
    // setHeight() does not ensure that specified 
    // height will be in effect, of course, for valid reasons.
    // So derivation of Bitmap image in the setHeight() method is not sure.
    setHeight(backgroundImage.getHeight() + topMargin + bottomMargin);
    if (bitmapBackgroundImage == null)
    {
        bitmapBackgroundImage = getScaledBitmapImage(backgroundImage, 
                                this.width - (leftMargin+rightMargin), 
                                this.height - (topMargin+bottomMargin));
    }
}

/**
 * Generate and return a Bitmap Image scaled according 
 * to the specified width and height.
 * 
 * @param image     EncodedImage object
 * @param width     Intended width of the returned Bitmap object
 * @param height    Intended height of the returned Bitmap object
 * @return Bitmap object
 */

private Bitmap getScaledBitmapImage(EncodedImage image, int width, int height)
{
    // Handle null image
    if (image == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getWidth());
    int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(image.getHeight());

    int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(width);
    int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(height);

    int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);
    int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);

    image = image.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);

    return image.getBitmap();
}


protected void sublayout(int width, int height)
{
    // We have one and only child - the edit field. 
    // Place it at the appropriate place.
    Field field = getField(0);
    layoutChild(field, this.width - totalHorizontalEmptySpace, 
                this.height - totalVerticalEmptySpace);
    setPositionChild(field, leftMargin+leftPadding, topMargin+topPadding);

    setExtent(this.width, this.height);
}

public void setTopMargin(int topMargin)
{
    this.topMargin = topMargin;
}

public void setBottomMargin(int bottomMargin)
{
    this.bottomMargin = bottomMargin;
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    // Draw background image if available, otherwise draw a rectangle
    if (bitmapBackgroundImage == null)
    {


     graphics.drawRect(leftMargin, topMargin, 
//                                width - (leftMargin+rightMargin), 
//                                height - (topMargin+bottomMargin));
            graphics.drawRoundRect(leftMargin, topMargin, 
                                   width - (leftMargin+rightMargin), 
                                   height - (topMargin+bottomMargin), 5, 5);
        }
        else
        {
            graphics.drawBitmap(leftMargin, topMargin, 
                                width - (leftMargin+rightMargin), 
                                height - (topMargin+bottomMargin),  
                                bitmapBackgroundImage, 0, 0);
        }

    // Determine the rightward text that can fit into the visible edit field

    EditField ef = (EditField)getField(0);
    String entireText = ef.getText();

    boolean longText = false;
    String textToDraw = "";
    Font font = getFont();
    int availableWidth = width - totalHorizontalEmptySpace;
    if (font.getAdvance(entireText) <= availableWidth)
    {
        textToDraw = entireText;
    }
    else
    {
        int endIndex = entireText.length();
        for (int beginIndex = 1; beginIndex < endIndex; beginIndex++)
        {
            textToDraw = entireText.substring(beginIndex);
            if (font.getAdvance(textToDraw) <= availableWidth)
            {
                longText = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (longText == true)
    {        
        // Force the edit field display only the truncated text
        ef.setText(textToDraw);

        // Now let the components draw themselves
        super.paint(graphics);

        // Return the text field its original text
        ef.setText(entireText);
    }
    else
    {
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}

public int getPreferredWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public int getPreferredHeight()
{
    return height;
}

protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time)
{
    if (ch == Characters.ENTER)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
    }
}

public String getText()
{
    return ((EditField)getField(0)).getText();
}

public void setText(final String text)
{
    ((EditField)getField(0)).setText(text);
}    
}
```

Comment: I have this code but this is for editfield and I want Textfield with scrollbar.